# How to create composer.json file needed in order to post a module on Magento Connect (Magento Marketplace)?

Tags: composer, magento-connect

I am a Magento developer, and I have to publish an extension module to marketplace. I created an account and I am a status of "partner", so on this page:
https://developer.magento.com/customer/account/edit/
I have a field with composer.json file, which I don't know what it's about. How do I create the composer file in order to publish the module to marketplace? I am getting an error message "The vendor name must be lowercase alphanumeric with dashes allowed" if I don't enter it.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see an example of the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "vendorname/modulename", // this name is from your repository
    "description": "VendorName ModuleName Module",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "VendorName\\ModulName\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

This file knows how to bring the module from your repository.

Comment: Thanks. When I enter the vendor name in the field on this page:
https://developer.magento.com/customer/account/edit/
I get a mesage "Vendor name validation" and a spinning arrow that keeps spinning until forever. Do you know what's the problem here?

Comment: You must add your **VendorName**, Ex. **Magento**,  **Amasty**

Comment: I did. I typed it in small letters (seems like capital letters are not allowed). And it keeps spinning.